# Java setting the super extended class from the a passed in object

Tags: java

I have a class like this

```
public class User implements UserInterface, Parcelable
{
    public User(int userID, String firstName, String lastName, String mobileNumber, Date dateAccountCreated)
    {
        this.userID = userID;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
        this.dateAccountCreated = dateAccountCreated;
    }
}
```

And I then have another class that extends into this:

```
public class Invitee extends User
{
    private int eventDescision; 
    public Invitee(User u, int eventDescision)
    {
        super() = u;
        this.eventDescision = eventDescision;
    }
}
```

Obviously this line `super() = u;` does not work. However, how can I achieve the this functionality where I pass the User object the invitee recieves and set it as the extended object without having to create another constructor? I know I can just the object as a variable with a getter and setter, however, I like the way it flows without doing this as and invitee is always user.

Comment: do you agree with some answer? mark one as correct or clarify your doubts in comments, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should rather be:

```
super(u.getUserID(), 
      u.getFirstName(), 
      u.getLastName(), 
      u.getMobileNumber(), 
      u.getDateAccountCreated());
```

Comment: either that, or add a constructor which takes an instance of User, and call super(u);

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming he doesn't want to change his `User` class, but generally you're right. :)

Comment: I'll do this then. I thought you would be able to do what I want. I think it should be possible.

Comment: Don't forget to provide getters for the `User` members.

Answer (score 4):

`User` you receive in `Invitee` constructor is a real instance and you are creating another one. You can not assign one instance in a super constructor, you only can copy it, with a copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot automatically pass an instance of the base class to the base class' constructor call (`super`) in the child class' constructor.

What you might want to do is pass the base class' properties in the `super` call.

For instance is User properties are not private:

```
public Invitee(User u, int eventDescision) {
  super(u.userID, u.firstName, u.lastName, u.mobileNumber, u.dateAccountCreated);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Use decorator design patter in Invitee
2. Define costructor User(User u)
3. as people manthioned before: use super() with all parameters

Remember that super is calling constructor of superclass, so you can't call constructor which is not defined.